# Visual Studio won't infer the type of variable after type check

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am looping through a `List<CComponent>` (CComponent is my class) and only want to run code on the ones which inherit from the `CPowerable` class (which inherits from CComponent). The problem is, there will almost never be a base CPowerable element, and usually only elements which inherit from that. So if I did `foreach (CPowerable i in list)`, that would cast them all to CPowerable.

When I added a type check instead like this:

```cs
foreach (CComponent i in neighbours)
{
    if(i.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(CPowerable)))
    {
        i.powerSources.Add(this);
        i.updateNode(this, this, false);
    } else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Visual Studio gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsoVE.png), when all elements that code will run on will inherit CPowerable, and therefore have these fields.
How can I make the compiler know infer that all those objects will inherit CPowerable?

Comment: You haven't asked a question, you just told a story about some code you wrote. What's your question?

Comment: For what it's worth, this really doesn't have anything to do with Visual Studio (well, other than it's a C# compiler error and the compiler is hosted within Visual Studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pattern matching for this:

```cs
foreach (CComponent i in neighbours)
{
    if(i is CPowerable powerableI)
    {
        powerableI.powerSources.Add(this);
        powerableI.updateNode(this, this, false);
    }
}
```

Note that the `else` with `continue;` isn't needed because there isn't anything else in the loop.

Alternatively, you can include a `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code file, and then use `.OfType<CPowerable>()`:

```cs
foreach (var i in neighbours.OfType<CPowerable>())
{
    i.powerSources.Add(this);
    i.updateNode(this, this, false);
}
```